# How to update a react state but only replace a particular object inside the array?

Tags: reactjs

```
const filters = (type, value, status) => {

    if(status === true) {
        setSelectedFilters([...selectedFilters, {type, value, status}])
    }
  
    if(status === false) {
       let filterStatus = selectedFilters.filter((obj)=>obj.value !== value)
       setSelectedFilters(filterStatus)
    }

    if(type === 'price') {
        
        if(value === 'min') {
            setPriceValues({minPrice: status, maxPrice: priceValues.maxPrice ? priceValues.maxPrice : highestPrice})
        }
        if(value === 'max') { 
            setPriceValues({maxPrice: status, minPrice: priceValues.minPrice ? priceValues.minPrice : lowestPrice})
        }

        setPriceFilter({type, minPrice:priceValues.minPrice, maxPrice: priceValues.maxPrice})
        //setSelectedFilters([...selectedFilters, priceFilter])
    }
}
```

The `filters` function is passed into multiple filter components, such as 'categories', 'manufacturer' and 'prices'. I've already done the 'category' and 'manufacturer' filtering, but the "price" filtering is a bit more complicated, because I need to be able to filter by min and max price, and the `filters` function is invoked on input change.

I am trying to figure out how to add the price object from `priceFilter` into the `selectedFilters` state so I can then filter through it and only get the selected price. I struggle with finding a way to properly update the `selectedFilters`, because the function is invoked on every change of price. As you can see, I've used another state to create an object containing the prices, and it gets replaced onChange, but how do I now add `priceFilters` into `selectedFilters` on every invocation of the `filters` function?

If I do this `setSelectedFilters([...selectedFilters, priceFilter])` then I'll be adding a new `priceFilter` obj on every change, and that's not what I want. I want to extract the `selectedFilters` again because it might contain other filter objects, BUT replace the `priceFilter` object only! How do I do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly? You need a re-think. As first step you should probably separate the different filters into their own handlers and deal with them separately. Although they're all 'filters' it seems that they can change independently so there's no reason to keep them together imo. Doing so creates possible problems - for instance, if `status === true` and `type === price` it looks like will have two calls to `setSelectedFilters` - is that what you want?

Comment: @WillJenkins I already fixed that :) I just used useEffect to update the state correctly. But now I'm struggling to figure out something else. How do I do `all except`? What I wanna do is if `all except` is selected, basically I need to do the opposite, i.e. add only the objs that do not match the filters inside `selectedFilters`. Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/czqr8197/ Can you please help me figure out how to do the logic?